# Empty contents in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a contenteditable div that acts as a textarea:

```
<div class="post" placeholder="Write a comment..." contenteditable="true"></div>
```

How can I empty the div through JS/JQuery so that it's clear of all values?

I've tried `$(".post").html("");` but it doesn't work properly.

Please help.

Comment: you forgot a double quote there !! if that didn't do the trick try the empty() function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(".post").empty();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/57524/)

[jquery empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: I've tried this as well, but whenever it sets it to empty, and then I go to type something else in the div, it puts the type flashing icon on the very right of the div and it doesn't let me type anything: [http://i.imgur.com/ZHnUPrt.png](http://i.imgur.com/ZHnUPrt.png)

Comment: then your problem somewhere else, because if you look in to demo, everything working. maybe you can create jsfiddle with your problem?

Comment: I found out that the problem was because of the placeholder. I had the following CSS which made the placeholder act as if it was a textarea: `.post[placeholder]:empty:before { content: attr(placeholder); color: #bababa; }`. Now I have to figure out a way to make the placeholder work again.

Answer (score 3):

In pure javascript a simple `elm.innerHTML='';` should work just fine:

```
<div class="post" placeholder="Write a comment..." contenteditable="true">
</div>
<button onclick="
  document.getElementsByClassName('post')[0].innerHTML='';
">clear</button>
```

Note that a div doesn't have an `placeholder`-attribute, you'd have to substitute a simple function for that, containing just one line:

```
for( var elms=document.getElementsByClassName('post'), L=elms.length
   ; L--
   ; elms[L].innerHTML=elms[L].getAttribute('placeholder')
   );
```

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNg5A/) of the above.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Not all browsers will have a flashing type cursor! Instead they often just clear the div and since the height shrinks back to 0 px you'd have nothing to hold on to, so to fix this, naturally you'd need something to select and reset your placeholder text:

```
<div class="post" placeholder="Write a comment..." contenteditable="true">
</div>
<button onclick="
  var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('post')[0];
  elm.innerHTML=elm.getAttribute('placeholder');
">clear</button>
```

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PWF34/).

Comment: This is giving me the same issue as the other answer where, when it clears the div, it will reset the flashing type icon to the right side of the div: [http://i.imgur.com/ivu6ssC.png](http://i.imgur.com/ivu6ssC.png)